# Influential observation (strategy) in linear regression model

Tags: regression, outliers, residuals, robust

Suppose I have dataset(518 observations):

```
df$SalesPrice df$SqFeet df$Garage df$Year df$Quality  df$Style   df$Lot        
    360.000     3.032         2     1972          2        1    22.221 
    340.000     2.058         2     1976          2        1    22.912 
    250.000     1.780         2     1980          2        1    21.345 
    205.500     1.638         2     1963          2        1    17.342 
    248.000     1.966         5     1972          2        1    18.902

data.frame':    518 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ df$SalesPrice: num  360 340 250 206 248 ...
 $ df$SqFeet    : num  3.03 2.06 1.78 1.64 1.97 ...
 $ df$Garage    : int  2 2 2 2 5 1 2 1 3 2 ...
 $ df$Year      : int  1972 1976 1980 1963 1972 1955 1975 1918 1992 1987 ...
 $ df$Quality   : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 1 2 ...
 $ df$Style     : Factor w/ 7 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ df$Lot       : num  22.2 22.9 21.3 17.3 18.9 ...
```

Where I want to build a model for variable SalesPrice as Y variable.

But first I checked influential observations:

[image]

Where dashed line is calculated by the formula:
p <- length(coef(model.lm2)) - 1
n <- nrow(lm2_df)
significant.dffit <- 2*((p + 1) / n)^0.5

where **n** is number of observations and **p** is number of coefficients without intercept.

As a result I got 43 influential observations out of 518.

My question is: what **are** the best strategies of dealing with such big amount of influential observations? Is robust regression the only good solution in this situation?